# How can i use Pool instead of Process & Pipe

Tags: python-multiprocessing

I have a first `tree` class that does some calculations, and another `forest` class that contains trees and does more calculations.

The `tree` class uses the `Pipe()` connection mecanism to fit a tree : the resulting nodes and leaves need to be `recv()` by the tree.

The `forest` class, after fitting a certain number of tree, uses also the `Pipe()` connection mecanism to compute other things depending on the trees, which are also `recv()` by the forest.

When the number of tree rises in the forest, i am running into `OSError : Too many open files` and cant increase the `ulimit` since i have no root access on the machine where the code is running.

I am gessing that using `Pool()` will not have theese problems. But i do not understand how i can transmit information using `Pool` between child and main processes. For the moment, i use an idiom that looks like :

```
from multiprocessing import Pipe, Process


class tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.random_number = 5 # Choosed by fair roll dice

    def start_fit(self):
        self.parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe(duplex=False)
        self.process = tree_fitter(self.random_number, child_conn)
        self.process.start()
        return None

    def join_fit(self):
        self.fitting_result = self.parent_conn.recv()
        self.process.join()
        self.parent_conn.close()
        del self.parent_conn
        del self.process
        return None

class tree_fitter(Process):

    def __init__(self, random_number, connection):
        self.connection = connection
        self.new_randm_number = 2 # Choosed by fair roll dice

    def run(self):
        result = self.new_randm_number * random_number
        self.connection.send(result)
        self.connection.close()
        return 0


class forest:
    def __init__(self,n_trees):
        self.n = n_trees  # Number of trees
        self.trees = [tree() for i in range(0,self.n)]

    def compute_more_complicate_things(self):
        processes = []
        parents = []
        results = []

        for i in range(0,self.n):
            self.trees[i].start_fit()

        for i in range(0,self.n):
            self.trees[i].join_fit()
            parent_connection, child_connection = Pipe(duplex=False)
            parents.append(parent_connection)
            processes.append(forest_cumulative_mean(self, i,child_connection))

        for i in range(0,self.n):
            processes[i].start()

        for i in range(0,self.n):
            results.append(parents[i].recv())
            processes[i].join()
            parents[i].close()
            print(i, end=" ")

        del processes
        del parents
        del results
        self.cumusum_of_result = results


class forest_cumulative_mean(Process):

    def __init__(self, forest, i, connection):
        self.trees = forest.trees[:i]
        self.connection = connection

    def run(self):
        result = sum([t.result for t in self.trees])
        self.connection.send(result)
        self.connection.close()
        return 0
```

1° How can i transform it to the `Pool` idiom without changing too much the structure of my code (this is of course a dummy example (i did not try to run it), i have a lot more code around it..).

2° Will this tackle the error i have about spanning too many processes ?

Comment: _(this is of course a dummy example (i did not try to run it), i have a lot more code around it..)_ Might it be worth sharing the actual program?

Comment: 5000 lines of code... Extracting a MWE from it would be a lot of work, sadly. But i totaly agree